# How to create .NET 4 C# class instance in Nemerle?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, nemerle

How to create .NET 4 C# class instance in Nemerle for example simple System.Object (or mofe complex class from .DLL)?

Comment: Did you tried anything so far? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 3):

Same as in C#, except without the `new` keyword. Just make sure you are using the .NET 4.0 version of Nemerle.
See the wiki for more information: https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/wiki.